# Use Insert as a shortcut for Insert keyframe?

Tags: keyframes, shortcut

The default shortcut for "Insert keyframe" is <kbd>I</kbd>, which is achieved by holding the mouse over for example the Location Transform, and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. I want to use the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key instead.

Even if I overwrite all the shortcuts that are called something with *Insert keyframe* and/or use the <kbd>I</kbd> key, it doesn't work. It's still the <kbd>I</kbd> key that is active.

Is there something special about the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key that makes it unusable? I noticed "Toggle overwrite" was using the <kbd>Insert</kbd>, but even if I turned it off, while all shortcuts were assigned to <kbd>Insert</kbd>, I still couldn't insert keyframes.

Anyone has a clue on this?

Comment: I could replace (on Windows) the I with Insert without problems.

Comment: @Ibalazscs At least in the User Preferences you cant. Note that Niclas mentioned hovering over a property, then pressing "insert". In all other context's it works fine.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe this one is hardcoded and cannot be changed.

Comment: Oh that's a pity. Instictively I keep pressing the insert button.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autohotkey to make the insert key function as the "i" key when Blender is open.

https://autohotkey.com/

Comment: Thanks, since a long time ago I got used to the I key and forgot that Insert would be logical:) I could also use Keyboard maestro for this.